# Unity 5.1 What Exactly Is Padding Power In The Editor Settings?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity 5.1 there is a setting called Padding Power with an option of 1 2 and 3 what exactly is this and when is each recommended?

Answer (score 4):

Padding is the space between sprites when you use sprite packer feature in unity. Some texture filter averages neighboring pixels, so a padding of 2 is recommended to avoid neighboring regions from affecting each other, it is Good for base and two mip levels. Generally you have to do trial and error to check which value is giving you desired result. Anyways unity uses padding power 2 in its Default Packer Policy.

Comment: OK... now with 5.2 the padding power is configurable in the Editor settings, and it's very nebulous what it means/does exactly! Is it a number of pixels? or mipmap level? just an arbitrary "high/medium/low" level, if so what's the order?